# CryptoSwift and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-swift-bridge, cryptoswift

How I can use CryptoSwift to my Objective-C project?

I have an Objective-C project and want to use Encryption Library CryptoSwift for that. I have successfully used the single Swift file into my Objective-C project, but how to use a Swift project as subproject to the parent project that was built in Objective-C.

I tried to use Cocoa pod too but to no avail.

Comment: Hello, I want to integrate CryptoSwift with Objective C iOS App, i have install CryptoSwift by using cocoapods, What should I do next??

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cocoa pods but on the target at the `build options` you should set  `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` to **YES**.

See [this](https://michiganlabs.com/ios/2015/07/22/swift-library-objectivec-project/) tutorial for a detailed description.

Comment: Hello, I want to integrate CryptoSwift with Objective C iOS App, i have install CryptoSwift by using cocoapods, What should I do next??